# Mapping map field to Ember Data

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I have response from server in this format :

```
{
 "id":"552cd25444ae47fe5f3a41b2",
 "eventType":"REST_EVENT",
 "userSid":"REST_USER",
 "content":{
           "key":"value",
           "key1":"value1",
           "key2":"value2"
  }
}
```

How I can map **content** field to Ember Data Model if this field has dynamic count of values and without knowing key names ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really simple. Use this in your model

```
content : DS.attr()
```

Ember will automatically pick up if you pass array, string or number. In your case array.

You can even iterate over it. Watch it using Observers like any other array or model attribute in Ember.